# Galilean telescope magnification coefficient?

Tags: geometric-optics, telescopes

[image: Telescopes]

So I've seen the magnification coefficient of the compound concave telescope to be $\frac{f_0}{f_e}$, but what is the magnification coefficient in the case of the convex galilean telescope?
This may be a dumb question but I'm terrible with angles.
If I have a telescope made of an objective convex lens with focal length $f_0$ and an eyepiece concave lens with focal length $f_e$ and I observe an object that is very far away and that it's rays of light come to the objective lens as parallel rays forming an agle of about $h_0/f_0$, I want to calculate the angle that the image observed forms, but I can't figure it out, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.